# How can I make '/etc/vim/vimrc' writeable?

Tags: permissions, vim

I tried with `chmod u+w vimrc` but it doesn't work. I also tried `:w!` and still doesn't work.

The point is that I make a mistake deleting some `"` in vimrc and now I don't know how to write it back there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should *not* be editing `/etc/vim/vimrc`, it is not your vimrc. Instead, edit `~/.vimrc`. If you *really* want to edit the global vimrc, you need make it writable by everyone:

```
chmod 666 /etc/vim/vimrc
```

Or make yourself the owner of the file

```
chown yourloginnameher /etc/vim/vimrc
```

Comment: chmod: changing permissions of `/etc/vim/vimrc': Operation not permitted

chown: changing ownership of `/etc/vim/vimrc': Operation not permitted

Why?

Comment: Because the file is owned by root. Why do you want to edit it instead of `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: I don't want, but I edited first this one, and I deleted the first character, and now every time I open a new file I get <b>Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vimrc:
line    1:
E492: Not an editor command:</b> . And I want to edit it, to write back the first character there .. (the first char was ")

Comment: ok, then use `sudo vim /etc/vim/vimrc` just this once to restore it. Then never edit it again :)